# Декораторы в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, декоратор

В связи с [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1154282/398802) возник такой.

Как правильно написать функцию, которая принимает другую случайную функцию, возможно что-то делает, вызывает принятую функцию, возможно опять что-то делает, а потом возвращает результат этой принятой функции?

При этом все типы должны сохраняться, то есть если принятая функция возвращает что-то по ссылке или по значению, то и результат функции-декоратора должен быть таким же. Параметры тоже должны передаваться идеально. **Не должно быть лишних копирований и перемещений** (может быть копирование результата исходной функции, только если этот результат нужен нашему декоратору (например, залогировать его), но такое копирование не лишнее, а необходимое). Если переданная функция выкидывает исключение, то *"опять что-то делает"* не происходит (то есть если у нас должен писаться лог после вызова исходной функции, то при исключении он не пишется). Если для исходной функции была возможна оптимизация возвращающего значения, то и для вызова декорирующей она должна быть.

Пример вызова такой декорирующей функции `log_invoke`:

```
struct A {} a;

auto foo = []() -> A  { return {}; };
auto bar = []() -> A& { return a; };

int main() {
    auto rvo = log_invoke(foo);
    auto no_rvo = log_invoke(bar);
}
```

Comment: `std::invoke` ?

Comment: @Croessmah как и где правильно его вызвать, чтобы, например, ещё напечатать то, что функция была вызвана с такими-то параметрами, и при этом все условия соблюдались?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename... Args>
requires std::invocable<F, Args...>
decltype(auto)
log_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    struct Logger {
        const int initial_exceptions_number{std::uncaught_exceptions()};

        Logger() {
            std::clog << "message before\n";
        }

        ~Logger() {
            if(initial_exceptions_number == std::uncaught_exceptions()) {
                std::clog << "message after\n";
            }
        }
    } logger;

    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Плюсы:

- Гарантированная оптимизация возвращаемого значения ([gcc и clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Yd54z5))
- Работает для функций, возвращающих `void`!
- Немного более понятная диагностика компилятора при вызове с неправильными аргументами из-за `std::invocable<F, Args...>` (но в другие решения концепт тоже элементарно добавить, так что это микроплюс)

Минусы:

- Читаемость? Но если делать обобщённую версию (в конструкторе принимать 2 функции), то объявление класса можно вынести за пределы функций-декораторов и в итоге функции будут состоять из двух строк: создания экземпляра класса с передачей 2 функций в конструктор и `return` стейтмента, что в итоге будет меньше, чем писать `constexpr if` (+1 ветка для возвращаемого типа `void` помимо уже существующих 2)
- Дополнительный `int` по памяти, 2 вызова функции и сравнение интов по времени
- Нельзя использовать возвращаемое значение

Тест:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>   

template<typename F, typename... Args>
requires std::invocable<F, Args...>
decltype(auto)
log_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    struct Logger {
        const int initial_exceptions_number{std::uncaught_exceptions()};

        Logger() {
            std::clog << "message before\n";
        }

        ~Logger() {
            if(initial_exceptions_number == std::uncaught_exceptions()) {
                std::clog << "message after\n";
            }
        }
    } logger;

    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct A {
    A()             { std::clog << "A()\n"; }
    A(const A&)     { std::clog << "A(const A&)\n"; }
    A(A&&) noexcept { std::clog << "A(A&&)\n"; }
};

A foo() { return A{}; }

int main() {
    const auto rvo = foo();
    const auto rvo_too = log_invoke(foo);

    std::clog << '\n';

    void (*void_foo_ptr)(int, int) = [](int x, int y) { std::clog << x << ' ' << y << '\n'; };
    log_invoke(void_foo_ptr, 1, 2);

//    const auto not_invocable = "I'm not invocable D:";
//    log_invoke(not_invocable);
}
```

Вывод:

```
A()

message before

A()

message after 

message before

1 2

message after
```

Comment: Замечу, что решение @dIm0n работает для простого логирования, но не для любого кода до и после. В частности, проблема может быть в случае использования корутинов до и после искомой функции. См. https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2023/04/23/the-obvious-final-step/.

Answer (score 6):

Слева привиндить не проблема:

```cpp
template<class Pre, class F> auto wrap(Pre &&pre, F &&f) {
        return [pre = std::move(pre), f = std::move(f)](auto &&...args) -> decltype(auto) {
                pre(args...);
                return std::invoke(f, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };
}
```

Добавить еще Post несколько сложнее, придется, вероятно, отказаться от std::forward в вызове f.

(`forward<decltype(args)>` — это по C++17-ному, в двадцатых можно в template parameters у лямбд.)

Если просто вызвать немного функций с одними и теми же аргументами:

```cpp
template<class F, class G, class... Args> decltype(auto) sequence(
                F &&, G &&g, Args &&...args)
{
        std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), args...);
        return std::invoke(std::forward<G>(g), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int &f(int &x) { return x += 2; }

int main() {
    int x = 38;
    sequence([](int x) { std::cout << "Initial x: " << x << '\n'; }
                 , f
                 , x) += 2;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

> Можете привести что-то типа call_and_log, которая вернёт результат переданной функции и залогирует то, что был совершён вызов?

Ох.

```cpp
template<class F, class... Args> decltype(auto) log_invoke(F &&f, Args &&...args) {
    std::clog << "f(";
    std::size_t i{};
    ((std::clog << (i++? ", " : "") << args), ...) << ") = " << std::flush;

    using RV = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>;
    RV rv = std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    std::clog << rv << '\n';
    if constexpr(std::is_reference_v<RV>) return std::forward<RV>(rv);
    else return rv;
}

int &f(int &x, int z) { return x += z; }

int main() {
    int x = 36; 
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    log_invoke(f, x, 4) += 2;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Ну да, это уже ближе, только мне не wrap нужен, т.е. возвращать не лямбду, а именно результат исходной функции. Да, и у меня 20 стандарт, так что пишите с темплейтами, если надо

Comment: Ну тогда совсем тривиально.

Comment: Пажждите, а откуда ещё 1 функция взялась, не понимаю? Можете привести что-то типа `call_and_log`, которая вернёт результат переданной функции и залогирует то, что был совершён вызов?

Comment: Ну вот в моем примере сейчас в main вызов sequence это и делает, в принципе, я просто абстрагировался от конкретного предварительного действия.

Comment: Сейчас если исходная функция выкинет исключение, то лог из первой функции будет записан всё равно

Comment: Хорошо, теперь так.

Comment: Спасибо, чуть позже посмотрю, сейчас уходить надо

Comment: Сорри, туплю немного с утра, вот, вроде бы, самая гламурная версия.

Comment: Смотрите, упростил ваш последний пример и выводит предупреждения, что возвращается ссылка, а не временное значение https://godbolt.org/z/Ko3rr1

Comment: Теперь, вроде, не должно.

Comment: Да, но теперь такая же проблема, как у другого ответа :) В том месте, где можно оптимизировать возвращающее значение, этого не происходит https://godbolt.org/z/xrrofY, т.е. не должно быть лишнего вызова перемещающего конструктора

Comment: Ну это уж вопрос к компайлер-вендорам, зачем они его туда положили.

Comment: @dIm0n GCC здесь делает NRVO. Интересно, почему Кланг его не осилил... В любом случае, других вариантов вроде нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat надо, чтобы осилили `gcc` и `clang`, на `msvc`, так уж и быть, попроще ограничения :)

Comment: @dIm0n Попробовал [вот так](https://godbolt.org/z/asWe74) - NRVO появился. Хмм...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat кстати, на `clang` появился, а на `gcc` то исчез! :)

Comment: @dIm0n Мда, ну тогда `#if __clang__`. И можно было бы еще обоим зарепортить как баги.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat есть одна идея без ифоф, если никто не ответит, попробую реализовать. Ещё +500 есть, так что не стесняйтесь давать ответ :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой ответ, мб не заметил какие-то минусы?

Comment: @dIm0n Выглядит ок. С `std::uncaught_exceptions` хорошо сделали, я бы наверное не догадался и написал `if (std::uncaught_exceptions() == 0)`. Плохо только, что возвращаемое значение не получится залогировать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо, добавил в минусы. А про догадки — так реализовано в Boost.Log :)

Comment: @dIm0n Угу, сам только что на cppreference прочитал. :)

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать такую конструкцию

```
struct A {} a;

auto foo = []() -> A {return {};};
auto bar = []() -> A& {return a;};

template<class Function>
decltype(auto) decorator(Function&& function){
    std::cout << "Decorator called" << std::endl;
    return std::forward<decltype(function())>(function());
}

int main()
{
    decltype(auto) rvo = decorator(foo);
    decltype(auto) no_rvo = decorator(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

[проверить работоспособность](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n8h1cM)

Если с аргументами, то такую

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
decltype(auto) decorator(Function&& function, Args&&... args){
    std::cout << "Decorator called" << std::endl;
    return std::forward<decltype(function(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>(function(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Если с исключениями

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
decltype(auto) decorator(Function&& function, Args&&... args){
    decltype(auto) result = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << "Decorator called" << std::endl;
    return std::forward<decltype(result)>(result);
}
```

Единственный минус в том, что если результат не ссылка и не определено перемещение, то будет копирование

В конце концов немного поигравшись я пришёл к выводу, что можно использовать такую конструкцию

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
decltype(auto) decorator(Function&& function, Args&&... args){
    auto&& result = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << "Decorator called" << std::endl;
    return std::forward<decltype(result)>(result);
}
```

Всё же реализация move конструктора всегда ложится на самого программиста, потому что старые варианты(без учёта исключений) без оптимизаций самого компилятора тоже будут вызывать копирование по несколько раз.
Вообще судя по логам, промежуточного копирования не происходит [тык](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bs4d1P)

Comment: Если функция выкинет исключение, то лог будет записан

Comment: Вот последний вариант уже ближе, но вы сами указали, в чём проблема :) Надо как-то обойти

Comment: Смотрите, ваш последний пример не делает оптимизацию возвращаемого значения, когда это можно сделать https://godbolt.org/z/osYvMM. Видите, для обычного вызова `foo` нет перемещающего конструктора, а для декорирующей функции - есть

Comment: Больше того, последний пример (c `auto &&result = ...`) не работает нормально, если `function` возвращает не ссылку.

Comment: Раз `function` - форвардинг-ссылка, перед вызовом я бы сделал `std::forward<Function>(function)`. Еще, в примере с `decltype(auto) result = ...` , `return std::forward<decltype(result)>(result);` ломается если функция возвращает не ссылку. Та же самая проблема с `return std::forward<decltype(function())>(function());`. Здесь `forward` вообще не нужен, `return function();` и все.