# Как помочь компилятору определить тип шаблонной функции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Имеются две функции-таймера `timerClock` и `timerQPC`, способных замерять время выполнения функции, переданной им в виде шаблонного параметра. Необходимо передать их в исследующую функцию `testingTimer`, внутри которой они будут вызваны. Набросал код, который реализует это.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>

const unsigned long long arraySize = 1'000'000'000;

void testFunc(double* parr, int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        parr[i] = parr[len] * std::sin(parr[i]);
    }
}

template<typename Func>
double timerClock(const Func& testFunc) {
    std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
    testFunc();
    return 1000 * (std::clock() - c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

template<typename Func>
double timerQPC(const Func& testFunc) {
    LARGE_INTEGER freq,
                  c_start,
                  c_end;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    double PFfreq = static_cast<double>(freq.QuadPart) / 1000;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c_start);
    testFunc();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c_end);
    return static_cast<double>(c_end.QuadPart - c_start.QuadPart) / PFfreq;
}

template<typename Func>
unsigned testingTimer(const Func& timer) {
    size_t len = 1000;
    double* arr = new double[1000000000];
    std::function<void()> funcBind = std::bind(testFunc, arr, len);
    while(!timer(funcBind)) {
        len += 1000;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << testingTimer(timerClock);
    return std::cout.rdstate();
}
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку: *no matching function for call to 'testingTimer'

Насколько я понимаю, это из-за того, что он не способен вывести нужный тип параметра. Каким образом можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Похоже, вам нужны [декораторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155804/Декораторы-в-c)

Comment: А ещё вижу `new`, но не вижу `delete`, и `size_t` без `std::`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что `timerClock` - это не функция, а шаблон функции. Это не одно и тоже. А вот `timerClock<SomeType>` - это уже функция. Именно её и нужно передавать в `testingTimer`. В Вашем случае, это `timerClock<std::function<void()>>`, потому что  именно `std::function<void()>` будет ей передаваться.
Если упростить Ваш код, то вот что получается:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

const unsigned long long arraySize = 1'000'000'000;

void testFunc(double* parr, int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        parr[i] = parr[len] * std::sin(parr[i]);
    }
}

template<typename Func>
double timerClock(const Func& testFuncArg) {
    std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
    testFuncArg();
    return 1000 * (std::clock() - c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

template<typename Func>
unsigned testingTimer(const Func& timer) {
    size_t len = 1000;
    double* arr = new double[1000000000];
    std::function<void()> funcBind = std::bind(testFunc, arr, len);
    while(!timer(funcBind)) {
        len += 1000;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << testingTimer(timerClock<std::function<void()>>);
    return std::cout.rdstate();
}
```

Comment: даже шаблон, а я и не заметил..