# Декоратор Python на С++

Tags: python, c++, шаблоны-проектирования, декоратор

Я задался вопросом, как можно реализовать простой декоратор на С++. В интернете о них есть информация, но без конкретных примеров мне сложно понять, как концептуально они реализуются. В питон декораторы реализуются достаточно просто и лаконично, ниже будет представлен код простого декоратора на Python(Без синтаксического сахара), который выводит время выполнения программы. Я бы хотел перенести его на C++, я отдаю себе отчёт, что скорее всего вариант на C++ будет полностью другим, но я бы хотел посмотреть на его реализацию, поскольку сам не представляю, как его можно сделать.

```
from time import time


def time_dec(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        start = time()
        s = f(*args)
        end = time()
        print(end - start)
        return s
    return wrapper


def func(n):
    return sum(i for i in range(n))


func = time_dec(func)

print(func(32323232))
```

Comment: в с++ под декоратором обычно понимают другое — [шаблон проектирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))… окромя названия, они имеют не много общего с питононовскими, а прямых аналогов питоновским декораторам (на уровне языка) в плюсах нет, т.к. обычные функции не являются объектами…

Comment: если очень хочется. то можно нагородить что-то [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679445/python-like-c-decorators) на `std::function` с шаблонами с переменным количеством аргументов, но использовать это всё также свободно как на питоне не получится…

Comment: Написать такой декоратор можно, и он будет почти такой же компактный, как в питоне. Но "здесь так не принято". Т.е. это не является сложившейся практикой написания кода, и поэтому, обязательно будет выкинуто при code-review. Принято писать - Scoupe-Guard-ы.

Answer (score 0):

Это дубликат [Декораторы в C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1155804).

Вот пример декорирования функции логированием:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>   

template<typename F, typename... Args>
requires std::invocable<F, Args...>
decltype(auto)
log_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    struct Logger {
        const int initial_exceptions_number{std::uncaught_exceptions()};

        Logger() {
            std::clog << "message before\n";
        }

        ~Logger() {
            if(initial_exceptions_number == std::uncaught_exceptions()) {
                std::clog << "message after\n";
            }
        }
    } logger;

    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct A {
    A()             { std::clog << "A()\n"; }
    A(const A&)     { std::clog << "A(const A&)\n"; }
    A(A&&) noexcept { std::clog << "A(A&&)\n"; }
};

A foo() { return A{}; }

int main() {
    const auto rvo = foo();
    const auto rvo_too = log_invoke(foo);

    std::clog << '\n';

    void (*void_foo_ptr)(int, int) = [](int x, int y) { std::clog << x << ' ' << y << '\n'; };
    log_invoke(void_foo_ptr, 1, 2);

//    const auto not_invocable = "I'm not invocable D:";
//    log_invoke(not_invocable);
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Если дубликат, то надо закрывать как дубликат, а не копировать ответ. :(